# How Does List<T>.Contains() Find Matching Items?

Tags: c#, .net, list, collections, contains

I have a list of car objects

```
 List<Car> cars = GetMyListOfCars();
```

and i want to see if a car is in the list

```
if (cars.Contains(myCar))
{
}
```

what does Contains use to figure out if myCar is in the list.  Does it do a "ToString()" on my car object.  Does it use the Equals() method, the gethashcode()?

I see i can pass in my own IEqualityComparer to force my own implementation but just wanted to understand what it does by default.

Comment: ToString returns the type's name when not overridden so it wouldn't be a good way to compare items :)

Comment: By the way, you can't pass your own `IEqualityComparer<T>` into the `List<T>.Contains` method. You *can* pass your own comparer into LINQ's `Contains` extension method, which works quite happily against `List<T>`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Straight from [MSDN - List<T>.Contains:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx)

> This method determines equality by using the default equality
>   comparer, as defined by the object's implementation of the
>   IEquatable(Of T).Equals method for T (the type of values in the list).
>
> This method performs a linear search; therefore, this method is an
>   O(n) operation, where n is Count.

So in the end it depends on how `T` implements [IEquatable.Equals()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131190.aspx). For most objects this is going to be a reference comparison, unless overriden. Same location in memory is the same object.

Comment: One exception to this is if you search for `null`, in which case `Contains` just does an `item == null` test directly rather than using the comparer.

Answer (score 5):

It uses Equals()

> This method determines equality by using the default equality
>   comparer, as defined by the object's implementation of the
>   IEquatable(Of T).Equals method for T (the type of values in the list).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx

Answer (score 1):

`Contains` will return `true` as soon as it can - that is once the first item that fits the criteria is found.

A `false` will be returned after *all* items have been iterated over.

In regards to *how* it does that - it will use reference equality for reference types if you do not override `Equals`.