# Why doesn't Contains call CompareTo nor Equals?

Tags: c#, equals, compareto

While comparing instances of a custom class, I noticed that a call to `Contains` doesn't work the way I expect it to. Assuming that the default comparison goes by the reference (pointer or whatever it's called), I implemented both `CompareTo` and `Equals`. I made sure to be implementing `IComparable`, of course.

It's still doesn't work and I get no hits when I put breakpoints on those methods.

What can I be missing and is the best option to use extension methods if I'm not?

```
public override bool Equals(Object input)
{
  return Id == ((MyType) input).Id;
}

public int CompareTo(Object input)
{
  return Id - ((MyType)input).Id;
}
```

Comment: You might need to override `GetHashCode()` and possibly `==` too. Which `Contains` are we talking about? The extension method in Linq? The one in List?

Comment: What class are you are calling `Contains` from?

Comment: Also, information on overriding Equals.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: @Cameron Hmm... How do I know if it's LINQ's or List's?

Comment: @SteveMitcham From `List<MyType> temp = ...;`

Comment: There's not really any magic or so going on, it largely depends on how your class you call .Contains(..) on implements that method. For List<T> e.g. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9264597/2591

Comment: @JörgB. I can't see the difference between that post's answer and what I'm trying... I overrode `Equals` but it's not being called. What am I missing?

Comment: @Andy J - it is hard to say what you are missing without seeing more of your code. The Equals method should be called if you call .Contains on the List<T> so if that is not happening, you are doing something else incorrectly. However it is not possible for us to help you further with just the information you have provided.

Comment: @Cameron Post your comment. That was it. And to me it's widely weird. When I override `GetHashCode`, the stuff work **but** it never enters it! It **only** enters `Equals` but that's **already** there... Unexpected indeed...

Comment: @user469104 Wrong. It's possible. And Cameron already spotted it. Please see my comment. Weirdness ahead.

Comment: @AndyJ if your MyType class implements IEquatable, you still "must" override GetHashCode() as most lookups are against instance's hashcodes' first, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2009/01/15/if-you-implement-iequatable-t-you-still-must-override-object-s-equals-and-gethashcode.aspx . Give it a try - override .GetHashcode() { return base.GetHashCode(); } and place a break point in there and see if it gets hit.

Comment: @JörgB. I only implement `IComparable`. Also, yes, as Cameron suggested, the thing works since I added `GetHashCode`. But it's never entering the method!

Comment: Code for List<T> here shows that you should be overriding == as well as Equals as Cameron said http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,cf7f4095e4de7646

Comment: Someone please put that as a reply so I can accept as an answer.

Comment: GetHashCode is a way to pre-check if things are equal without performing the whole compare.  Two things with the same hash code are supposed to be equals. Theoretically, the hashcode is supposed to be a faster compare than the whole object but most people don't implement it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

A better implementation could be:

```
public bool Equals(MyType other)
{
    // if 'other' is a null reference, or if 'other' is more derived or less derived
    if ((object)other == (object)null || other.GetType() != GetType())
        return false;

    // OK, check members (assuming 'Id' has a type that makes '==' a wise choice)
    return Id == other.Id;
}

public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    // call to other overload
    return Equals(obj as MyType);
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return Id.GetHashCode();
}
```

You can mark the class as implementing `IEquatable<MyType>` in that case (but it will work even without that).

Regarding `GetHashCode`: ***Always*** remember to override it. You should have seen a compiler warning that it was problematic to override `Equals(object)` without overriding `GetHashCode`. ***Never*** keep the code `return base.GetHashCode()` in the override (assuming the base class is `System.Object`). Either give it a try and implement something based on the members that participate in `Equals`. If you do not think `GetHashCode` will actually be used in your case, say:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    throw new NotSupportedException("We don't have GetHashCode, sorry");
}
```

If you absolutely know that you will only be using `List<>.Contains`, and not e.g. `Dictionary<,>`, `HashSet<>` and not Linq's `Distinct()`, etc. etc., it could work with `GetHashCode()` simply throwing.

`IComparable<MyType>` is not needed unless you *sort* `List<MyType>` or `MyType[]`, or you use Linq's `OrderBy` with `MyType`, or you use `SortedDictionary<,>`, `SortedSet<>`.

Overloading `operator ==` is not needed for these uses.