# c# contains object not working

Tags: c#, list, contains

I am trying to create a check between lists, but am having no luck :-/

I have a game board with 100 fields and make this loop to add only empty fields into a new list:

```
for(int i = 0; i < thisGame.boardFields.Count; i++)
{
    if (thisGame.boardFields.Count != 0 && thisGame.boardFields [i] != null) 
    {
        BoardField thisField = thisGame.boardFields [i];
        if (thisField.owner == "0" && thisField.number != 13) 
        {
            Tile tTile = new Tile();
            tTile.color = thisField.color;
            tTile.number = thisField.number.ToString();

            tempBoard.Add (tTile);
        }
    }
}
```

Then I loop through the players 5 tiles to see if the player has a tile which is not playable, e.g. a empty field with the same object is not available like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < thisGame.playerTiles.Count; i++)
{    
    Tile tempTile = new Tile();
    tempTile.color = thisGame.playerTiles[i].color;
    tempTile.number = thisGame.playerTiles[i].number.ToString();

    if (!tempBoard.Contains (tempTile)) 
    {
        testTile = tempTile;
        print ("HUSTON WE HAVE A PROBLEM: " + tempTile.color + "-" + tempTile.number);
    }    
}
```

This is the definition of the Tile class:

```
public class Tile 
{    
    public int id;
    public string color;
    public string number;   
}
```

Now my problem is, that it prints on every 5 tiles in the players tile list? All tiles in the players tile list is available in the `tempBoard` list?

What am I missing her?

Hoping for help and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Please show class definition of tile

Comment: @Gilad Green Please see edited post

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To work `Contains` needs to check equality between two objects. By default, for reference types it does it by checking reference equality. Therefore, having two different instances (objects in memory) of same type and with same values to all properties will still result in them being not equal, and for `Contains` to return false.

To overcome this 3 options:

1. you need your class to override the `Equals` and `GetHashCode`
   methods of object. References on overriding the methods:

   - [What is the best algorithm for an overridden System.Object.GetHashCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/263400/6400526)
   - [Guidelines for Overriding Equals()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147.aspx)
2. Another option instead of overriding the methods in your class is to create a class implementing the `IEquatable<Tile>` interface and then use the overload:

   ```
   list.Contains(searchedTile, new SomeClassImplementingInterface());
   ```

   Id use this in case the overriding of the `Equals`/`GetHashCode` are non-trivial (do not include all properties of the class) or if you do not have control over the `Tile` class.
3. Use linq's `Any` method:

   ```
   collection.Any(item => item.number == tempTile.number && item.color == temTile.color);
   ```

---

Also, it is nice to initialize your objects using the [object initializer syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers):

```
Tile tTile = new Tile
{ 
    color = thisField.color,
    number = thisField.number.ToString()
}
```

---

And if you have your fields `public` they should probably be defined as properties:

```
public class Tile 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

About properties vs fields:

- [What is the difference between a Field and a Property in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/295104/6400526)
- [Public Fields versus Automatic Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1180860/6400526)

And last have a look at [naming conventions for C#](http://www.dofactory.com/reference/csharp-coding-standards)

Comment: Trying to figure this out, what is: new TileEquatable()?

Comment: Sorry for not understanding. What is that class? Whats in it?

Comment: @Mansa - updated answer to make a bit more clear. Basically it is a class with the implementation of the interface

Comment: This is way over my head :-/ I thought I had my shit together, but I simply do not understand that part, but thanks for trying ;-)

Comment: @Mansa - you do not have to use the interface. The first part explains about the overriding. That is probably the correct way to go

Comment: @Mansa - see update clarifying the different options and additional one. I still think going for option 1 is the correct way and in terms of how advanced the least - so good to start with

Comment: Many thanks for your explanation. I will go with the collection.Any() for now but look deeper into the override method.

Answer (score 0):

According to this Stack Overflow answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/9264597/1102726), if you don't provide an overide for `IEquatable. Equals`, `Contains` will do a reference comparison. Since you had just instantiated `tempTile`, it will
never be in that list. You can either provide that override in your definition of `Tile` or change out the `Contains(tempTile)` for something like `tempBoard.Any(t => t.number == tempTile.number)` or however you define two tiles being the same.

Comment: Is it possible to add 2 fields to: tempBoard.Any(t => t.number == tempTile.number)? I need to check if the object has both the number and color?

Comment: You can do anything you'd like, so long as it evaluates to a boolean true/false value. You would then do `t.number == tempTile.number && t.color == tempTile.color`.

Comment: `Any` the way I'm suggesting basically says, "let's go through every item in the collection, let's call the item `t`, let's check to see if some boolean expression involving  `t` evaluates to `true`, and if so, we'll say `Any` returns `true`.

Comment: Oh, and to clarify, you'll have to have `using System.Linq;`